# C programming conditional operator

Tags: c

So simple but there is one thing that I could not understand.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

     int main () {

     int n=15, p=10, q=5;
     q=n<p? n++: p++;
     printf ("n=%d p=%d q=%d \n" ,n,p,q);

      return 0;
     }
```

While using the conditional operator, it checks if(5=15<10) n++ else q++

Answer: n=15 p=11 because the statement is false and q=10 and not 15. why is that?
so q=p instead of q=n.

Can anyone explain it to me please?

Comment: `=` is an assignment, a comparison would use `==`. But comparing 3 values still doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
q=n<p? n++: p++;
```

Means

```
if (n < p) {
  q = n;
  n = n + 1;
} else {
  q = p;
  p = p + 1;
}
```

Look at your code this way (this is how compiler sees it):

```
q = ((n < p) ? n++ : p++);
```

What you probably want is this:

```
(q=n)<p? n++: p++;
```

Compiler sees this as:

```
q = n;
if (q < p) {
  n = n + 1;
} else {
  p = p + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> it checks if(5=15<10) n++ else q++

Not true.

```
q=n<p? n++: p++;
```

is an **assignment**.

The C draft in section `6.5.16.1` p2 says:

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted
>   to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored
>   in the object designated by the left operand.

In your case,it just that the value of the right operand is deduced from the expression `n<p? n++: p++`.

Also as you have two prefix expressions `n++` and `p++` the value of `n` and `p` before the increment is taken into account depending on the branching.

Answer (score 2):

check the `conditional` operator `associativity`, its Left to Right .

```
q=n<p? n++: p++;
```

first `n< p` is solved which is `false`, so result will be `p++` 
so `q = p++;` // here `p` value also `change` but first 10 is assigned to q because of post increment

finally `p` becomes `11`  and `q = 10`

Answer (score 1):

Its not that much confusing
These are increment statements
Pre increnent or post increment.
So
A++ 
Means value of A is used first in the expression and then it will increment
And
++A 
Means value of A us increment first then used.
Ao in the expression

```
int n=15, p=10, q=5;
q=n<p? n++: p++;
```

As `n<p` is false
And then it resembles to

```
q = p++
```

It means

```
q = p
```

Then `p = p+ 1`.
Hope this will clear the doubt..

Answer (score 1):

The q= is an assignment operator so it is not part of the evaluation.

Your conversion to the if statement should really be

```
if (n < q) {
    q = n;
    n++; 
} else {
    q = p;
    p++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
q=n<p? n++: p++;
```

properly written:

```
q = (n<p)? n++: p++;
```

means that the variable: q will be set to either n or p, depending on if the value in n is less than the value in p or not.

So the initial value in q is meaningless